# Sort table with jQuery but keep groups of rows together?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, tablesorter

I have a CodeIgniter project that loads a table of data, an Account Name in the first column then indented in the first column it loads that accounts sub-brands. Then the 2nd thru 8th column are other datapoints I'd like to sort on. In this table sorting on sub-brands would be useless so I wouldn't allow it.

I just installed the TableSorter plugin but it sorts on every row in the Accounts/Brands column, but I just need it to sort on account name and keep the groupings of account+brands together, not split them up.

So if I have layout:

```
Account
   Brand A DataPt1 DataPt2...
   Brand D DataPt1 DataPt2...
   Brand 4 DataPt1 DataPt2...
Account
   Brand Alpha DataPt1 DataPt2...
   Brand IV DataPt1 DataPt2...
Account
   Brand # DataPt1 DataPt2...
```

How could I sort on account and have the brands move with them? I can adjust the column layouts if account+brand would need to be separated etc

Comment: #1: improve your accept rating
#2: htp://whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: Check out [this demo](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-child-rows.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this [TableSorter mod](http://blog.pengoworks.com/index.cfm/2008/3/28/Finished-jQuery-Tablesorter-mod-for-Collapsible-Table-Rows) which adds support for collapsible rows. It works great, I would like to change it a bit so instead of a +/- button to expand and collapse rows you could just click anywhere on the row though.

Answer (score 1):

I think more than codeigniter solution, you need a client-side solution that displays data as you wish.

You can use  [JQGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) (see section Grouping) and test if it covers your needs. On the server side, you only need to capture and display model data via [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php)